# Where classes live? Models or lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've inherited a rails project that I am looking to refactor. The app uses ActiveRecord very lightly; most of the calls are to REST endpoints. Right now the classes that make these calls are in the lib directory. I've been reading a couple of [posts regarding the lib directory](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/), and I'm wondering the rationale why the original developer did not use the models directory (there must be some reason) and what are the pros/cons of moving these classes into the models directory.

It "feels" like these classes should be in the models directory as they are core to the application.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I'm doing, put in the models folder all the classes that are responsible for working with the database. If it's libraries or classes
,which not realy dependent on the datebase and can be used in different projects
then it can be put in the lib folder.

Comment: I agree with that approach but out of my 15-ish classes only one is backed by ActiveRecord but they all contain CRUD-like logic with REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If your classes are not quite model-related (ActiveRecord), you should consider putting it in a place more specific then models, but if you do put it in model, put them in an enclosed folder.

app -> models -> endpoints
Inside config -> application.rb, put this line of code in to load it

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/models/ar)
```

Or you can flat out put it in a separate directory
app -> endpoints

The reason for this is because your REST endpoints will be isolated; your business logic will be more "clean" and modular with less clutter if you are planning to build more stuff on the application.